# Get the value of a constant within a class dynamically

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML to parse an XML API.

The API returns several child elements like this:

```
 ...
 <Rank0>Something</Rank0>
 <Rank1>Something</Rank1>
 <Rank2>Something</Rank2>
 ...
```

When to access `<Rank1>`, for example, I can do the following:

```
$response->Result->Rank1;
```

However, I need to loop through these values dynamically. In pseudocode, something like this:

```
foreach($response->Result>Rank*){
    echo "looping through rank" . $number;
    echo "value is" . $value;
}
```

How do I do this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can normally iterate an elements children, have you tried this on the parent element?
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.children.php):

```
foreach($response->Result->children() as $child_node)
{
    // do something with $child_node
}
```

If you need to verify that the node name is in the form of "Name" + *number*, you can add a condition inside your loop like the following:

```
if(preg_match('/^Rank\d+$/', $child_node->getName()))
{

}
```